# How can I completely suppress hyphenation that starts in a column (or page) and ends in a second one?

Tags: line-breaking, two-column, paragraphs, hyphenation, columnbreak

[image]

In the example above, the hyphenation of the word 'deterministic' starts in one column and ends in the next one. How can I suppress this behavior altogether?

**NOTE:** I know that `\mbox{<text>}` forces the text to stay in one line, but the text of the document changes by editing and the same issue may arise with different words. What I want is to set a parameter or use a package with certain option that will detect and not allow this from happening in general.

My MWE

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}


\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\vspace{11\baselineskip}


Aside from speed improvement over exhaustive search method, our fast screening method has the following \mbox{\emph{advantages}}:
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\arabic*)]
    \item it heavily relies vector-based analysis making it amenable to be understood by a typical power system operator or engineer,
    \item it is based on deterministic algorithm that does only relatively simple vector-based calculations. Thus, it does not require thorough expertise to write a code to implement it,
    \item valid in realistic power grid under different voltage levels.
\end{enumerate*}
While the \emph{disadvantage} is that interactions among magnitudes and angles are not taken into account, but rather we separate them since we regarded them as \enquote*{quasi-mutually exclusive.} Such assumption, however, does not seem to affect the accuracy of results as we demonstrate in this \mbox{Section with extensive numerical simulations}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
\brokenpenalty=10000
```

Probably better: use the `widow-and-orphan` package that wil hit ctan during the next days (and will have an article explaining it). That package allows you to generate warnings if that problem arrises and you can then decide what the appropriate action is.

If you want the package now it is at

https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex/tree/widows-and-orphans-1.0a/widows-and-orphans

Enforcing a 100% compliances (through the above setting) may not always give you the optimal result.

#### Upate

The package is now available on CTAN and in distributions such as TeX Live etc.